# Remember-me doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I succeded to implement remember-me using spring boot security and store data in my table persistent_logins(username,series,token,last_used) and find it in coockies in my browser. my problem is when i delete the Jsessionid from my browser and refresh it the browser redirect to login page and don't still in the same page:

this is my SecurityConfigWeb.java:

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/sentEmail").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/contactUs").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/reset").permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATTERN1).permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATHPATTERN2).permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATHPATTERN3).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());       
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage(Constants.URL_PATH).successHandler(this.authSuccess).failureHandler(this.authFailure).permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccess).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable();}
@Bean
public BCrypt bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCrypt();
}


@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

}

@Bean   
public AbstractRememberMeServices rememberMeServices() {
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices rememberMeServices =
        new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices("AppKey",userDetailsService(),persistentTokenRepository());
    rememberMeServices.setParameter("rememberMe");
    rememberMeServices.setAlwaysRemember(true);
    rememberMeServices.setCookieName("javasampleapproach-remember-me");
    rememberMeServices.setTokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60);
    return rememberMeServices;
}



@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;}
```

and this is my login.html for remember-me:

```
<div class="checkboxDiv">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="true"> <label class="check" for="checkbox">Stay Logged In</label>
                    </div>
```

Any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You only have remember me enabled for pattern3. Your security config is weird just chain everything in 1 call...

Comment: sorry M.Deinum i don't get you you mean i should do this: http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATTERN1).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATHPATTERN2).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATHPATTERN3).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());       ???

Comment: No you should have 1 chain to configure your security...

Comment: one chain you mean relation with login or logout , this:         http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccess).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
 ? no?

Comment: Something like that yes (also why the extensive configuration for the logout, you are basically reconfiguring the defaults).

Comment: because i'm newbie for spring security: sorry for this question but which configuration i should reconfigue ??

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you configured your security in several statements instead of making use of the fluent api.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(Constants.PATHPATTERN3).permitAll().and().rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices());
```

With this line you activated the 'remeber me' functionality but only for `Constants.PATHPATTERN3`. So if you want to activate remember me for all your endpoints your security configuration should be something like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

   http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/sentEmail", "/contactUs", "/reset", Constants.PATTERN1,Constants.PATHPATTERN2, Constants.PATHPATTERN3).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
      .logout()
        .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccess).permitAll()
    .and()
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage(Constants.URL_PATH)
        .successHandler(this.authSuccess)
        .failureHandler(this.authFailure).permitAll()
    .and()
      .rememberMe()
        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
        .key("AppKey")
        .alwaysRemember(true)
        .rememberMeParameter("rememberMe")
        .rememberMeCookieName("javasampleapproach-remember-me")
        .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
    .and()
      csfr().disable();      
}

@Bean
public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
    JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
    tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return tokenRepository;
}
```

This way you configure everything in one go.

Comment: Maybe adding a little more information about what the original problem was and why your code fixes it would improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @M. Deinum I'm sorry for respond late but it's still the same when i retrieve the jsessionid i get the login page and this the exception i get:   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException:173 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Accès refuséorg.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:149)

Comment: Then you don't have a remember me cookie... Make sure that the name of the remember me parameter matches the configured one. Also instead of configuring the service manually I suggest using the namespace.